# Is Russian Kale suitable for freezing?

Tags: storage

I have a lot of Russian kale and would like to know if there is a way to keep around for a couple of months?

Answer (score 4):

As described at [Pick Your Own](http://www.pickyourown.org/freezing_greens.htm), you can freeze kale like any green.  The technique is fairly similar to many vegetables:

1. Clean the greens, and remove the toughest parts of the stemps.
2. Blanche briefly in boiling water, then shock in an ice water bath to halt the cooking
3. Drain and dry.
4. Freeze, perhaps in a zip-type freezer bag.